# How to run a Referenced Model inside a Matlab Function Block in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, function, simulink

Is it possible to run/simulate a referenced simulink model(of subsystem A) from inside a Matlab function block of another model(Model B)? My design requires me to run a simulation of a subsystem A inside another model B. I cannot directly use the referenced model of the subsystem A in my main model B because it is time dependent and the output of the subsystem A is used as an input in the main model B. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608436/simulink-how-to-run-a-simulation-in-a-simulation), your approach to "replace your simulation subsystem by a Matlab Function block that runs/calls the referenced model as a simulation independent of the main simulation" should work "perfectly fine".

Comment: Thank you. I had seen that post but I couldn't understand how I can run/call the referenced model inside the Matlab Function block. Do you know what command I can use for this? I searched but could only come up with the usual run command but that doesn't need the model to be a referenced model. I hope you know better than me in this area. Maybe you can suggest some ways?